# Listing all files installed by some MacPorts package

Tags: macports

How to list all files that was installed   by some MacPorts package?

For example in Funtoo (or in Gentoo) I can achieve the same with a command:

`equery b [package name]`

Comment: related (reverse): [Find a macports package given a file name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25460320/127971)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

```
port contents installed_port_name
```

Comment: and for anyone interested, the reverse lookup (which port provided a file) is `port provides filename`

Comment: reference: https://guide.macports.org/#using.port.contents

Answer (score -1):

In my case the CFLAGS LDFLAGS were necessary.

```
# ensure libyaml is installed
port install libyaml +universal

# if you like you can check the location of the installied files (especially the .h file)
# port contents libyaml

# now configure with these options
CFLAGS="-I/opt/local/include/ "  LDFLAGS="-L/opt/local/lib/" ./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: This answer is not related to the question!