# Cannot install graphviz with macports

Tags: install, macports

I am struggling with macports trying to install [graphviz tool](https://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=graphviz):

```
... $ sudo port install graphviz
--->  Computing dependencies for graphviz
--->  Fetching archive for graphviz
--->  Attempting to fetch graphviz-2.40.1_1+pangocairo+x11.darwin_18.x86_64.tbz2 from https://packages.macports.org/graphviz
--->  Attempting to fetch graphviz-2.40.1_1+pangocairo+x11.darwin_18.x86_64.tbz2 from http://mse.uk.packages.macports.org/sites/packages.macports.org/graphviz
--->  Attempting to fetch graphviz-2.40.1_1+pangocairo+x11.darwin_18.x86_64.tbz2 from http://lil.fr.packages.macports.org/graphviz
--->  Fetching distfiles for graphviz
--->  Verifying checksums for graphviz
--->  Extracting graphviz
--->  Configuring graphviz
--->  Building graphviz
--->  Staging graphviz into destroot
--->  Installing graphviz @2.40.1_1+pangocairo+x11
--->  Activating graphviz @2.40.1_1+pangocairo+x11
--->  Cleaning graphviz
--->  Scanning binaries for linking errors
--->  No broken files found.
--->  No broken ports found.
... $ graphviz
-bash: graphviz: command not found
... $ which graphviz
... $ sudo port installed
The following ports are currently installed:
...
  graphviz @2.40.1_1+pangocairo+x11 (active)
...
```

Literally have no idea what did I wrong. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes when you install command line software, the software is actually a package that contains a collection of binaries (or library source files) and according to the [Portfile](https://github.com/macports/macports-ports/blob/master/graphics/graphviz/Portfile) description of graphviz, it's one of those packages:

> The Graphviz layout programs dot, neato, fdp, sfdp, twopi and circo
>   take descriptions of graphs in a simple text language, and produce
>   output in a variety of visual and text formats.

I personally don't use MacPorts but according to [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/47547) it seems like you can view the binaries (and library source files) installed by a package through:

```
port contents installed_port_name
```